# SEHexception occured while calling .net com dll from c++ after upgrading .net 2.0 into .net 4.0

Tags: c#, c++, asp.net, .net, dll

My project is used c++ layer to access .net com dll from other platforms.Firstly I developed com dll in .net 2.0 version.Everything is ok.There is no problem.we registered dll with using regasm.exe and then it worked correctly,Then i want to upgrade my project into .net 4.0. I opened the project with vs 2010 and conversion was completed succcesfully.there was no problem while building.But we came across a weird error during tests.it firstly gives class not registered and then sehexception (0x80004005).I searched everything  but i cant find solution. What should i do..Thank you so much for help.

Old Batch File for registering .net 2.0

```
path C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727
RegAsm.exe AkosLibraryCs.dll  /tlb:AkosLibraryCs.tlb /codebase
```

Batch File for registering .net 4.0

```
path C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319
regasm.exe  AkosLibraryCs.dll  /tlb:AkosLibraryCs.tlb /codebase
```

Getting Error this line:

```
IAkosFunctionPtr akosFunc(__uuidof(AkosFunction));
```

**c++ code**

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "tchar.h"
#import "AkosLibraryCs.tlb" raw_interfaces_only
 using namespace AkosLibraryCs;
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) _TCHAR* runFunction(_TCHAR*  functionCode, _TCHAR*  params) 
{
void* resultAsVoid;
try
{
IAkosFunctionPtr akosFunc(__uuidof(AkosFunction)); ***//getting error this line!!!!!!!!***
void* functionCodeAsVoid=(void*)functionCode;
void* paramsAsVoid=(void*)params;
akosFunc->runFunction(functionCodeAsVoid,paramsAsVoid, &resultAsVoid); 
}
catch(_com_error& ex  )
{
LPCWSTR str = TEXT("Hata Oluştu");
MessageBox(0,ex.ErrorMessage(),str,0);
throw;
}

return  static_cast<_TCHAR*>(resultAsVoid);
}
```

Comment: Are you sure the regasm.exe you are using is the 4.0 one?

Comment: yes i also give regasm.exe path in batch file above.anything wrong in batch file lines ?

Comment: Is there any error when regasm the dll?

Comment: Only it gives a warning,old version gave same warning too but it worked correctly

RegAsm : warning RA0000 : Registering an unsigned assembly with /codebase can cause your assembly to interfere with othe
r applications that may be installed on the same computer. The /codebase switch is intended to be used only with signed
assemblies. Please give your assembly a strong name and re-register it.
Types registered successfully
Assembly exported to 'C:\...\AkosLibraryCs.tlb', and the type library was regist
ered successfully

Comment: Did you unregister the old DLL with regasam /u?

Comment: Yes,it is exactly unregistered,unregistering batch is

`path C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727`
`RegAsm.exe /unregister AkosLibraryCs.dll  /tlb:AkosLibraryCs.tlb /codebase`

Comment: Search in the registry with the uuid of the class AkosFunction, if it is in the right place, then the register process is fine.

Comment: Does the user account running this have launch/access permissions on the COM object?

Comment: Yes user is administrator that has all accessible permisions

Comment: By the way,when HResult runs to create instance,it gives 0x80040154 error.What it means ?